# Getting the x-axis coordinates in bar graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the value of each bar to my bargraph. I'd like to write the value of each bar in the middle of it. I know how to find the mid points on Y axis but I don't know how to get the mid points on x-axis. If I some how get the beginning point and the end point of each bar, the we can find the mid point but I don't know how. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this issue? 
Here is my code:

```
G3.AllLevels.data$pos = G3.AllLevels.data$ProfChange*0.5

ggplot(data=G3.AllLevels.data, aes(x=ProfLevel, y=ProfChange, fill=TRTstatus)) + 
   geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), colour="black") + 
   scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(198, 64, 5, maxColorValue=255), 
                     rgb(33, 80, 186, maxColorValue=255))) +
   ylab("Change in %Students in Each Level") + 
   xlab("Achievement Levels") + 
   opts(axis.text.x  = theme_text(size=12), 
        axis.title.x = theme_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y = theme_text(angle = 90, size=14))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the numerical coordinates, as long as you construct a second data frame with your labels correctly:

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
        geom_bar(position="dodge")

lab_dat <- unique(diamonds[,c("cut","clarity")])
lab_dat$y <- 4000
lab_dat$lab <- with(lab_dat,paste(cut,clarity,sep = "-"))

p + geom_text(data = lab_dat,aes(y=y,label = lab),
                angle = 90,size = 2,position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joran... The part **position = position_dodge(width = 1)** was actually the missing piece of the puzzle. Without that, all the label per each clarity level are printed on top of each other.